# 50 amp GFCI to Plug-On-Neutral subpanel?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, gfci, subpanel, hot-tub

I'm adding a subpanel that will include service for a hot tub. The panel I have selected happens to be a Square D Homeline 125 amp 8-space 16-circuit PON. I'll be using a Square D Homeline 50 amp GFCI for service to the hot tub. My problem (if it is one), the 50 amp GFCI has a pigtail. I've not found a 50 amp GFCI without the pigtail and is instead plug-on-neutral.

Do all GFCI's have a pigtail?

Comment: Is it a Square D "QO" panel or a Square D "Homeline" panel? It matters for breaker compatibility. This is, however, effectively a shopping question and is likely to be closed. I'd suggest that you skip the big-box stores and instead contact your local electrical supply houses, if it's available, they'll have it. Whether you'll be able to get your hands on one in a reasonable amount of time is another matter... (I was quoted a minimum 4 _months_ to get a new panel!)

Comment: Additionally, there really isn't a problem to use the pig-tail on the breaker, Just screw it down (to the proper torque setting) on the neutral bus bar, just like you'd land any other neutral wire there.

Answer (score 2):

### Use a HOM250GFI, just make sure to land the pigtail before plugging the breaker on

The Homeline PoN panels still have neutral screws on their neutral bars, so there's no issue with installing a pigtail neutral Homeline breaker (such as the HOM250GFI you're looking at using for your hot tub) into a PoN Homeline panel.  Just land the neutral pigtail on one of the neutral screws for that spot before you install the breaker into the panel; that way, the breaker won't interfere with access to the neutral screws.

Answer (score 0):

> The panel I have selected happens to be a...

### GFCI breakers *are not* back-fed

Normally, it's possible to take a main-lug subpanel and "give it a main breaker" by installing it in the corner, *with a tie-down kit so it can't rock out*, and bringing the supply wires onto its (normally output) terminals. This means "back-feeding" the breaker: Power is going "wrong way" through the breaker, and plain breakers don't care. **But you can't do that with GFCI**.

GFCI-protecting a whole subpanel happens one of two ways.

- Use a "spa panel" which has a very special bus arrangement so the GFCI breaker is fed in the forward direction.  That panel typically *comes with* the GFCI breaker included.
- Place the GFCI breaker in the main panel, at the other end of the feeder cable.

However, if you place the GFCI breaker in the main panel, *then you must use the correct model of GFCI breaker for **that** main panel*.  So a plug-on neutral will only work if that panel takes it.  So for instance if it is a Murray panel, you'd use a Siemens QF250P.  A bit of good news here: you may have the option of a 60A GFCI breaker since they're available for all panels *except* HOMeline. (Homeline is Square D's "cheap" line, and they limit it on purpose).

**Breakers *are not* interchangeable across panel brands**. Many people think they are - and they do *physically* fit. However the bus stabs are not the same shape, and they are likely to burn up the bus, making the 2 bus spaces unusable, and even start a fire.  We see it all the time.

Comment: Thanks for all the great info all